# Clear input with is binded to event using button

Tags: c#, html, blazor

Hi I am using a Blazor framework for simple project, so in short words I have a input and a button:

```
<input type="text" id="modal_table_autosearch" placeholder=" " @oninput="@(async args => await this.Filter(args))" />
<label for="modal_table_autosearch">Search by name</label>
                
<button type="button" @onclick="@(async _ => await this.Filter(null))">
    <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
</button>
```

As you see when I start typing in my input event is fired, and when I press this button bellow, I want it to reset result and clear input.
Well reset thing works, but I have no idea how to clear input. I could just move operations to property and do things there, but I feel this will grow and property will not be enough.

And here is my event code:

```
     protected async ValueTask Filter(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Value?.ToString()))
        {
            this.SetFilteringCollections();
            return;
        }

        var searchValue = args.Value?.ToString();
        // thing I do with string but I think there will be more complicated object pass as argument that's why event

        await this.InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of you code.  Bind the input to a property, or a property in a model.

You're also overcomplicating the Async Blazor events wrapping tasks inside tasks.

```
@page "/Test"
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Value" @bind-value="InputValue" @oninput="this.Filter" />
<label for="modal_table_autosearch">Search by name</label>

<button type="button" @onclick="() => this.Filter(new ChangeEventArgs { Value= null }))">
    Clear Value
</button>
@code {

    private string? InputValue { get; set; }

    protected async Task Filter(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Value is null)
        {
            InputValue = null;
            // this.SetFilteringCollections();
            return;
        }
        var searchValue = args.Value?.ToString();
        // simulate some async work
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```